# Bayesian Optimization, return combination of different metrics as evaluation

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, loss, hyperparameters

I'm using bayesian optimization with gaussian processes to optimize my recurrent network parameters.

I'm getting pretty good results. I'm returning the validation loss of the last epoch as a feedback for the optimization algorithm.

I really would like to include some other parameters inside the feedback of each iteration, e.g. like training duration and the amount of modell parameter, because I want to find a small model with a good performance without changing the values of the parameter to a smaller range. 
Problem is that I don't know the scale of the loss. If a just scale the other parameters between 0 and 1, the loss has probably to less influence if it's always in the range 0.02-0.01. In this case the smallest model would be picked, but it would have a bad performance.

Thanks for your ideas. Cheers!